# Selecting random numbers or Times across a moving window in R

Tags: r, random, subset

I have a data frame of images collected along a transect.  The idea is that we want to randomly sample across the images (approx 1000 per transect).  We want to do this by selecting them randomly across a moving window (consisting of either 20/30 seconds, or of every 10-15 records). So select 1 image in the first 20 seconds of the mission, 1 from 21-40 seconds, and so on.

Useful fields include:

Date.Time (factor) in format: 20161102 101440
Date.Time.Local (POSIXct) in format: 2016-11-02 10:14:40
Mission.Time (int): 192 (seconds into mission, will not start at 1 for usable images and goes up by 2-3 each time)
FILENAME (factor): 20161102_hb01_0049.jpg

If it is possible to spit out the filename selected with the randomly selected record that would be an added bonus.

Any help would be great as I can currently only think of very lengthy ways to do this by defining the range to select each one seperately but this also wouldn't be reproducible across transects

Thanks, that is great! It seems to work for selecting a window of number of images but not by time when applied to my data as they don't go up in equal intervals.

> head(s)
>                        FileName            DateTime
>   223 20161102_hb01_fs_0049.jpg 2016-11-02 02:38:03
>   224 20161102_hb01_fs_0050.jpg 2016-11-02 02:38:05
>   225 20161102_hb01_fs_0051.jpg 2016-11-02 02:38:08
>   226 20161102_hb01_fs_0052.jpg 2016-11-02 02:38:10
>   227 20161102_hb01_fs_0053.jpg 2016-11-02 02:38:13
>   228 20161102_hb01_fs_0054.jpg 2016-11-02 02:38:15

Comment: please provide a `dput` of (a part of) your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s<-data.frame(DateTime=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-11-02 10:40:00"), by="sec", length.out=100), FileName=paste0(rep("file-",100), 1:100))
window<-20 
sampleSize <-5
groups<-seq(1, nrow(s), by=window) #indexes of first element in each window
result<-lapply(groups, function(x) s[sample(x:(x+window-1), sampleSize), "FileName"]) #for each group, randomly select sampleSize number of elements
```

Edit: splitting by time interval

```
s<-data.frame(DateTime=as.POSIXct("2016-11-02 10:40:00") + sample(1:200, 100, replace = T))
s$FileName<-paste0("file-",rownames(s),"-",format(s$DateTime, "%H%M%S"))
s<-s[order(s$DateTime ),] #Order date time from old to recent

sampleSize <-5
window.sec<- 25

split <- seq(min(s$DateTime), max(s$DateTime), by=(window.sec+1)) # splitting into groups 
#[1] "2016-11-02 10:40:02 MYT" "2016-11-02 10:40:28 MYT" "2016-11-02 10:40:54 MYT" "2016-11-02 10:41:20 MYT" "2016-11-02 10:41:46 MYT"
#[6] "2016-11-02 10:42:12 MYT" "2016-11-02 10:42:38 MYT" "2016-11-02 10:43:04 MYT"

groups<- c( sapply(split, function(x) min(which(s$DateTime>=x))) , nrow(s))  #indexes of first element in each group, and include the last index. 
#The first element in each group can be more recent than that in the split, if x is n.
# > s[groups,]
# DateTime       FileName
# 56 2016-11-02 10:40:02 file-56-104002
# 53 2016-11-02 10:40:30 file-53-104030
# 60 2016-11-02 10:40:56 file-60-104056
# 95 2016-11-02 10:41:20 file-95-104120
# 81 2016-11-02 10:41:46 file-81-104146
# 57 2016-11-02 10:42:12 file-57-104212
# 39 2016-11-02 10:42:39 file-39-104239
# 59 2016-11-02 10:43:04 file-59-104304
# 75 2016-11-02 10:43:20 file-75-104320

result<-lapply(1:(length(groups)-1), function(i) s[sample(groups[i]:(groups[i+1]-1), sampleSize), "FileName"])
names(result) <- as.character(split)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great! It seems to work for selecting a window of number of images but not by time when applied to my data as they don't go up in equal intervals. head(s) of my data put into the main problem